# Yahoo pipes translation module missing

Tags: module, translation, yahoo-pipes

I try to build an yahoo pipe, in order to translate RSS feeds from different languages into one. Searching the web there are a lot of examples and tutorials from the last 2 years. Searing through the yahoo pipes from other users, there many pipes, ready to clone...

...but if i like to build my own, in need the translate module. This is normally part of the "string" submenue.

But i can't find an translation module. There is no one!

The translate module still exists at the [yahoo pipes documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=string#Translate)
but is not available at my pipes source code editor.

Is this module removed by yahoo? Or may I have to "activate" something before I can use pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original translation tool (Babelfish.yahoo.com) was shut down earlier in 2012, so the translation module stopped working.

The Yahoo Pipes blog recently described a new replacement method you can use: http://pipes.yqlblog.net/2012/12/10/pipes-translate-module/

Comment: Oh jeah - that works. Thank you. But Microsoft / bing translate API is restricted to 2.000.000 characters per month, which is not so much. Did you have an additional idea?